# WP_query is not returning the expected result

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I have 2 dropdown lists, when a user select value in the first list, there is an ajax call to a function using `WP_query` which send results to populate the second dropdown.

My `WP_query` is not returning any result. I'm new to `WP_query` so I should have made a mistake somewhere.

The query should return the posts having the meta_key `_wpcf_belongs_marque-type_id` with the meta_value equal to the parent id sent by ajax. The posts should also have the post_type 'aromes-type'.

Here is the function located in my `functions.php`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_brand_children', 'GetBrandChildren');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_brand_children', 'GetBrandChildren');



function GetBrandChildren() {

    $output = '';
    //retrieve POST data sent by AJAX
    $parent_id = $_GET['parent_id'];

    //Define query arguments
    $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'aromes-type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => '_wpcf_belongs_marque-type_id',
                    'value'   => $parent_id
                ),
            ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    );


    //Create the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                $output .= '<option>' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
        endwhile;
    else:
            $output = '<option>No flavors found...</option>';
    endif;

    echo $output;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
}
```

The JQuery making the call :

```
//On selected brand, update flavors list
  $(document).on('change', "select[id^='marque']", function() {

        var $brandid =  $(this).val();
        var $brand_dd_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var $flav_dd_id = $brand_dd_id.substr($brand_dd_id.length-1);

        //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
        $.ajax({
                url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
                beforeSend: function(){$("#arome"+$flav_dd_id+".ul.select2-results").empty();},
                data: {
                        'parent_id': $brandid,
                        'action': 'brand_children'
                      },
                success: function(output) {
                    console.log(output);
                    $("#arome"+$flav_dd_id+".ul.select2-results").append(output);
                    $("#arome"+$flav_dd_id).trigger("chosen:updated");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
        }});

});
```

Comment: how is `GetBrandChildren` gets called?

Comment: I updated my post with more information

Comment: Have you checked the network tab(or your `console.log()`) for what is being returned from the Ajax call? You should be using [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) instead of `the_title()` by the way. `the_title()` echoes the title, and this might be breaking your response.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your question, You should hook `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_localize_script()` as shown in the Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Thank you !, I'm getting the good result now,I had serveral problem. First like you said the function the_title() was breaking my HTML, secondly it was not returning results because the content wasn't translated in WPML.
For the hook, I had already done that, I was just missing from my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => YOUR_POST_TYPE,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wpcf_belongs_marque-type_id',
            'value'   => $parent_id
        )
    )
);
```

In your loop set an `else` statement just to sure that you query isn't returning zero results:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $output .= '<li class="active-results">' . the_title() . '</li>';
    endwhile;
else:
    $output = 'No items here :(';
endif;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. The query still return no results. I don't know why because this query in phpmyadmin return rows for my parent_id :
select p.id,m.post_id,m.meta_key,m.meta_value from wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m where p.post_type='aromes-type' and p.id=m.post_id and m.meta_key='_wpcf_belongs_marque-type_id'

Comment: I would suggest you to turn on `WP_DEBUG_LOG` in your `wp-config.php`, re-test, and see the `wp-content/debug.log`.  This way we can have sure that your code is not breaking when the ajax request occurs.

Comment: Thanks bruno, I tried but no log generated. It makes sense because the code is not failing, I'm not just getting the expected result.

Comment: Can you try to `echo json_encode($the_query->found_posts); exit;` just after the `$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );`part of your code, and post the result here? Ps. I have the habit to always `json_encode` my ajax responses, maybe you could try.

Comment: it shows : 436
So it founds all the posts of the 'aromes-type' type.
This confirms that the filter with the parent_id is not working :(

Comment: Is the data stored in `_wpcf_belongs_marque-type_id` an array?

Comment: No it is a single value representing the parent post of type 'marque-type';

Comment: When you `console.log(brandid)`, what do you get?

Comment: Also, you'll be able to see the SQL query generated by your code if you `var_dump($the_query);` right after `$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );`. This can help you to debug this query. :)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I've been able te retrieve the query, I'll analyze it to see if I can find something wrong.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution, when you use a meta_key it automatically create a meta_query with the OR operator.
I updated my post with the correct query, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I've seen your update, but the `relation` should default to `AND` (as we can see in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query) `'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"` and in the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L967) at line 967. Maybe it is a wordpress bug.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues It could be that it's being set to `OR` by a filter of some sort.

Comment: @m0r7if3r I'm not taking the answer down. Let's just hope the OP comes back and accepts his own answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You right Bruno, the AND is optional, I tried without it and it is now working, not sure why, here is the code :

```
function GetBrandChildren() {

    $output = '';
    //retrieve POST data sent by AJAX
    $parent_id = $_GET['parent_id'];

    //Define query arguments
    $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'aromes-type',
    'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => '_wpcf_belongs_marque-type_id',
                    'value'   => $parent_id
                ),
            ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    );


    //Create the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                $output .= '<option>' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
        endwhile;
    else:
            $output = '<option>No flavors found...</option>';
    endif;

    echo $output;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer and not the one that did _not_ work for you. Thank you.

Comment: But the answer worked @kaiser, he is using the meta_query as I said. ;)